# Not able to telnet to client using 'telnet-client' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-modules

I am able to do telnet using the command prompt but getting an error through NodeJs

```
  'use strict'

  const Telnet = require('telnet-client')

  async function run() {
    let connection = new Telnet()

    let params = {
      host: 'linuxserver123',
      port: 1603,
      shellPrompt: '/ # ',
      timeout: 4500
    }

    try {
      await connection.connect(params)
    } catch(error) {
    }

    let res = await connection.exec('uptime')
    console.log('async result:', res)
  }

  run()
```

I am getting below error:

This error is coming from `connect()`

```
errer connecting Error: Socket ends
    at Socket.socket.on (project/lib/index.js:110:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:12139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: socket not writable
(node:12139) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Can you use a different port #? Higher than 1024. Ports below 1024 are system reserved and that could be causing an issue. Also put a try/catch block around `await connection.exec` and catch/log the error so you get more information than `UnhandledPromiseRejection...` gives you

Comment: getting same error with higher port `port: 1603`

Comment: @ChristopherReid The restriction only applies to the server, not the client.

Comment: @Barmar good point! There isn't much information to go off of here though, so I'm just dreaming up possibilities. Getting an actual error log and not a PromiseRejectionWarning would be helpful.

Comment: @ChristopherReid Are you really expecting something more detailed than `Error: socket not writable`?

Comment: @Barmar an actual error stack will show where the error is coming from in code and could be useful for understanding the issue more. Maybe not though. Either way, try/catch should be used here to stop the promise rejection warning and properly handle errors. Otherwise, this is potentially something wrong with the server and nothing to do with the code.

Comment: @ChristopherReid If you have your own try/catch, you don't get the stack trace from where the actual error occurred.

Comment: I have included `try catch` and updated the output in my question. I am getting `socket ends`

Comment: @meallhour Is that error coming from `connect` or from `exec`? Don't catch the connection errors without logging them, and without stopping `run`.

Comment: This error is coming from `connect`